# General questions about entering minutes into an Excel worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I'd like to be able to enter minutes into Excel cells and have another cell that totals the minutes.  I have no problem converting minutes into hours.  However, when I enter information, I don't want to always have to enter a colon.
Example:  I don't want to enter ":05" for 5 minutes.  I'd like to just enter "5".

Is that possible?
Could someone help me out with what cell format to use?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Read this [http://superuser.com/questions/235555/entering-time-data-in-excel-in-mmss-format-without-the-leading-0-for-the-hour]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are entering the minutes in Column A, rows 1 through 99.
Format column A as number, no decimals.

To sum the minutes use

```
=Time(0,Sum(A1:A99),0)
```

Format this cell as a Time 00:00:00.

Comment: Wow.  So simple.  Thank-you very much for your help!!!