# Converting number string to a time format: hh:mm

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Excel Text string to Time](https://superuser.com/questions/51887/convert-excel-text-string-to-time)

I must enter appointment times in a workbook.

For instance I have cell `E2` to input the time. I'll input, lets say `1500`. How can I change `1500` to `15:00`.

I have tried several `=TIMEVALUE()` statements I have found but when I put in the string `1500` or similar, the result that appears in the cell is `0:00` and the formula bar shows current date and time.

Comment: are you simply trying to put a colon in the middle of a 4 character string?

Comment: Question is similar to http://superuser.com/questions/51887/convert-excel-text-string-to-time

Answer (score 2):

Lets take CELL `A1` contains `1500`. To achieve the result, there are many ways to do.

Lets go with one-by-one.

Now you can do this way, to achieve one type of result:-

```
=TEXT(REPLACE(TEXT(A1,"##-##"),3,1,":"),"h:mm AM/PM")
```

**OR**

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&":"&RIGHT(A1,2), "h:mm AM/PM")
```

**OR**

```
=TIME(LEFT(A1,2),RIGHT(A1,2),0)
```

### OUTPUT:

```
3:00 PM
```

If you want only adding a colon in between, then do this way:-

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&":"&RIGHT(A1,2)
```

**OR**

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&":"&RIGHT(A1,2), "h:mm")
```

**OR**

```
=TEXT(A1,"##\:##")
```

### OUTPUT 2:

```
15:00
```

Comment: Nice answer. However, re the output as `3:00 PM`, this of course can be controlled simply by formatting the cell with the appropriate time format given your 3rd option in particular.